# .Net Compact Framework 3.5 HTTP POST

Tags: compact-framework, http-post

I'm writing my first Windows CE app using the .NET Compact Framework v3.5.
I need the app to be able to do an HTTP POST to a URL.
It appears that the .NET CF does not have System.Web.
So, I could use some guidence on how to accomplish and HTTP Posts using the .Net CF.
Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this satisfy your needs?

You need to import
   System.IO
   System.Net
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest

```
Try
   Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("<The server>"), HttpWebRequest)

   Request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True
   Request.KeepAlive = False
   Request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
   Request.ContentType = "text/html"
   Request.Method = "POST"

   'If required
   'Dim proxyURI As New Uri("193.129.241.46", UriKind.Absolute)
   'Dim webProxy As New WebProxy
   'webProxy.Address = proxyURI
   'webProxy.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("", "")
   'Request.Proxy = webProxy

   Dim requestStream As Stream = Request.GetRequestStream
   Dim Writer As New IO.BinaryWriter(requestStream)
   Writer.Close()

   Dim Reader As New BinaryReader(Request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream)
   Reader.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
   Throw ex
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTPWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest_members.aspx) exists in the CF and can be used for posting and scraping the response.  A quick search found several promising desktop articles on using them for doing POSTs, many of which can likely be ported.